# Acquiring waveform of LeCroy oscilloscope with PyVISA

Tags: python, instrumentation, pyvisa, oscilloscope

I am trying to acquire a waveform from a LeCroy Teledyne HDO4024A oscilloscope. I'm using the [LeCroyDSO library](https://lecroydso.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) and I've been able to communicate with the oscilloscope. For example, I could change the vertical scale with:

```
from lecroydso  import ActiveDSO, LeCroyDSO
connection_string = 'VXI11:168.252.89.210'
dso = LeCroyDSO(ActiveDSO(connection_string))
dso.write_vbs('app.Acquisition.C1.VerScale=1')
```

To retrieve a waveform, I've tried various approaches, all without any luck:

```
data = dso.get_waveform('C1')       
data = np.array(dso.query_vbs('CURV?'))
data = np.array(dso.query_vbs('app.Acquisition.C1.Out.Result.DataArray'))
```

I've also tried `dso.write_vbs`, and removing the `np.array()`. But none of these work. The first line doesn't return any variable, the second returns a `str544` with value `ndarray object of numpy module` and the third returns a `str` with value `Cannot convert Variant to string`. I don't know what to do from here. How can I retrieve the waveform data?

Comment: Looks like the second was what you were looking for. Although I don't know what a `str544` is.

Comment: Did you manage to solve the `Cannot convert Variant to String` problem?

Comment: No sorry. But there are some github projects that facilitate the communication with LeCroy oscilloscopes out there and are maintained. Don't remember the name though.